# botbuilder-applicationinsights - Enable Logging for User utterances

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-application-insights

I am using `[ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient][1]` module for logging `Dialog` data into Application insight. 
But it has some fields only.

```
-> InstanceId 
-> DialogId
-> StepName
```

etc.

Is it possible to add user utterance or extra key value pairs on top of this ?

Or [Direct](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-applicationinsights#use-with-waterfall-dialogs) logging is better .

Thanks in advance .. !

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this easily. You have a couple of different options:

#### 1. Create your own Dialog Class that extends [`WaterfallDialog`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/waterfallDialog.ts)

It would mostly be a copy/paste, but you'd need to add in the items you want tracked in [the steps that contain `this.telemetryClient.trackEvent`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/waterfallDialog.ts#L143).

#### 2. Use the [Direct](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-applicationinsights#use-with-waterfall-dialogs) approach

If you have a lot of dialogs, this will be more work, but will also help you track *exactly* what you need for each step. `TrackEvent` would likely make the most sense for you:

```js
appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name: "my custom event", properties: {customProperty: "custom property value"}});
```